# How to create 2 bootstrap rows with equal heights AND they must stack when resized

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've used the following CSS and HTML, my columns are equal height but no longer stack when viewing on smaller resolutions:

```css
.row-eq-height {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
}
```

```html
HTML
<div class="container-fluid"> 
  <div class="row-eq-height">
    <div class="col-lg-6" style="background-color:#23282D;">
     This is an example of the left hand column
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6" style="background-color:white;">
      This is an example of the right hand column
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this is helps. You need to add media query to make the column width 100% when the screen width is less than break points. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/overview/#responsive-breakpoints

760px can be varied depending on required screen size. Refer to css grid framework like bootstrap.

```
 @media screen and (max-width: 760px) {
    .col-lg-6 {
       width: 100%;
    }
 }
```

```css
.row-eq-height {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.col-lg-6 {
    display: flex;
    width: 50%;  /** is included in bootstrap css for all column */
}
.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 1em;
}

 @media screen and (max-width: 760px) {  /* This is included in bootstrap css */
    .col-lg-6 {
       width: 100%;
    }
 }
```

```html
HTML
<div class="container-fluid"> 
  <div class="row-eq-height">
    <div class="col-lg-6" style="background-color:#23282D; color: #fff;">
     <div class='content'>This is an example of the left hand column</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6" style="background-color:#dfdfdf;color: #23282d;">
      <div class='content'>This is an example of the right hand column. This is an example of the right hand column. This is an example of the right hand column. This is an example of the right hand column. </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`display: flex` is what's making your content display as columns. Put that rule inside a media query, so that it only activates on larger resolutions:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 960px) {
    .row-eq-height {
        display: flex;
    }
}
```

NB. It's not clear which version of Bootstrap you're using: if you're using version 4, all rows should be equal height by default. So you could just change `.row-eq-height` to `.row`.

Comment: Thanks guys I appreciate all the help

Comment: No problem - if my answer (or someone else's) has fixed your problem, please mark it as accepted :)